# How to display specific user data from $route.params.id to my component in vue js laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm new at Laravel & VueJS and I'm trying to display specific user details by using the `$route.params.id` to get specific user id of a user. As you can see inside `getUserdata()` method I'm trying to `console.log` the *this.userdetail* but its **undefined**
[console log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Q3m.png)

My Vue component

```
 export default {
    data(){
        
    return {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        userdetail: {},
    };
},

    methods:
    {
         getUserdata()
        {
            axios.get(`getuserdata/${this.id}`).then((response) => 
                {
                    this.userdetail = response.data.data
                    console.log(this.userdetail)
                }).catch((error) => 
                {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        },
    },
    mounted()
    {
        this.getUserdata()
    }
}
```

My web route

```
Route::get('getuserdata/{id}', [UserController::class, 'getUserdetails'])->middleware(['auth']);
```

UserController

```
public function getUserdetails($id)
{
    $userpost = DB::table('posts')->where('id', $id)->get();
        
    return response()->json(['data' => $userpost]);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting user data inside the `getUserdetails()` function?

Comment: yes, I tried to dd($userpost) with an existing id in my database and it gives me a result

Comment: I think you'll need to debug a couple of things. First, check whether the ajax is been successful.  If not with the dev tools check whether the data property id is getting the right value. If everything afterward is okay then you'll need to check your response.data.data by console logging it. Perhaps it is returning undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In your .then function of the axios call you wrote `response.data.data` The last `.data` is too much.